# Microsoft Azure MySQL purchase unavailble

Tags: mysql, azure, web-applications

In Microsoft Azure portal (This one: https://portal.azure.com/?l=en) I am trying to get Web app+MySql from Market. But I am recieving an error message while creating db, while web app can be created.

**Error is the following:**

```
{"error":{"code":"ResourcePurchaseValidationFailed","message":"User failed validation to purchase resources. Error message: '[\"The Offer is not sold in the account market (AZ).\"]'"}}
```

Has anyone ever face such kind of problem?

As I understood it is a location specific problem that I can not purchase MySQl. Are there any possible solutions?

I have contacted Microsoft Azure Support team and they have forwarded me here.

Comment: Got the same problem trying to automate the creation of a SendGrid account using an ARM template, the issue appears to be related to the account you are using. However, I tried elevating the account permissions in AAD and that didn't seem to fix it either.

Comment: This [tweet](https://twitter.com/jimwooley/status/498888275558686720) sheds some light on the problem, seems like you need to have a valid credit card associated with the account (even for free services).